# CSS not formatting page due to incorrect usage of div id tag or could it be due to files not called right?

Tags: html, css

It's like I try something one day and it works and I go back to virtually the same thing the next day with a few different tweeks and it doesn't work :////.

** the css is posted below but it' supposed to be on a different page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
<title> #Sandbox </title>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sandbox.css">  </head>
<body>

<div id="boxone"> One </div>
<div id="boxtwo"> Two</div>   
</body>    

</html>
.boxone {font-size:40;background-color: red;padding: 20px;}

.boxtwo {padding:20px;background-color: blue;}
```

Answer (score 2):

id selector has to be prefixed with `#` in css:

```
#boxone {
font-size:40;background-color: red;padding: 20px;
}

#boxtwo {
padding:20px;background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using gave `boxone` and `boxtwo` an `id` attribute, this should be `#boxone` and `#boxtwo` in CSS, if you don't want to change your CSS file then give them a `class` attribute in the HTML:

```
<div class="boxone"> One </div>
<div class="boxtwo"> Two</div>
```